How to choose vacuum value for monolayer and heterostructure?
I have read several articles but I am confused how to choose vacuum in case of 2D materials. Should we add vacuum of 20A in one side of monolayer or 10, 10A on both side of monolayer?
Kindly suggest me the correct way of doing calculations.

Will this answer your question?

okay. Thank you
